# read a file, after seeing a fullstop, shift the sentence to the next line

Tags: ruby

input file:

> Ruby is a dynamic, reflective, object-oriented, general-purpose
>   programming language. It was designed and developed in the mid-1990s
>   by Yukihiro "Matz" Matsumoto in Japan.According to its authors, Ruby
>   was influenced by Perl, Smalltalk, Eiffel, Ada, and Lisp.

output file:

> Ruby is a dynamic, reflective, object-oriented, general-purpose
>   programming language.
>   It was designed and developed in the mid-1990s
>   by Yukihiro "Matz" Matsumoto in Japan. 
>   According to its authors, Ruby
>   was influenced by Perl, Smalltalk, Eiffel, Ada, and Lisp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Stanford Natural Language Parser](http://stanfordparser.rubyforge.org/).

```
require "stanfordparser"

input = 'Ruby is a dynamic, reflective, object-oriented, general-purpose programming language. It was designed and developed in the mid-1990s by Yukihiro "Matz" Matsumoto in Japan. According to its authors, Ruby was influenced by Perl, Smalltalk, Eiffel, Ada, and Lisp.'
preproc = StanfordParser::DocumentPreprocessor.new
puts preproc.getSentencesFromString(input)
# Ruby is a dynamic, reflective, object-oriented, general-purpose programming language. 
# It was designed and developed in the mid-1990s by Yukihiro "Matz" Matsumoto in Japan. 
# According to its authors, Ruby was influenced by Perl, Smalltalk, Eiffel, Ada, and Lisp.
```

Using regex:

```
puts input.split(/((?<=[a-z0-9)][.?!])|(?<=[a-z0-9][.?!]"))\s+(?="?[A-Z])/)
# Ruby is a dynamic, reflective, object-oriented, general-purpose programming language.
#
# It was designed and developed in the mid-1990s by Yukihiro "Matz" Matsumoto in Japan.
# 
# According to its authors, Ruby was influenced by Perl, Smalltalk, Eiffel, Ada, and Lisp.
```

**Note:** I am assuming there is a space between `.` and `According` in your input string.

Comment: Standford parser i got an error but using regular expression its working! :) can you explain how did you write the regex? so that i can use it to align a c code too. @shivam

Comment: did you install the gem before trying StanfordParser? Install it by: `gem install stanfordparser`

Comment: yes i did, I had no idea the standford parser, i will try again. but the regex works really on mark!